# UIImage loading with @2x in iPad iOS7 is different with iOS8?

Tags: ios

I found the result of loading image is different in different iOS version.

environment1: iPad3,4 iOS7.02

```
//image scale is 1
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"momo05@2x.png"]; 
// image scale is 2
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"momo05"];
```

environment2: iPhone5s iOS 8.1

```
// image scale is 2
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"momo05@2x.png"];
```

why the result of image2 in environment1 is different with environment2? but the image1 in environment1 seems work alright.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the information in the Quick Help:

This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method locates and loads the image data from disk or asset catelog, and then returns the resulting object. You can not assume that this method is thread safe.

On a device running iOS 4 or later, the behavior is identical if the device’s screen has a scale of 1.0. If the screen has a scale of 2.0, this method first searches for an image file with the same filename with an @2x suffix appended to it. For example, if the file’s name is button, it first searches for button@2x. If it finds a 2x, it loads that image and sets the scale property of the returned UIImage object to 2.0. Otherwise, it loads the unmodified filename and sets the scale property to 1.0. See App Programming Guide for iOS for more information on supporting images with different scale factors.

On iOS 4 and later, if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension. Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension.

If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your image using imageWithContentsOfFile:. This will keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory use characteristics of your app.

Comment: thanks for your help, but what I want to know is why image2 in environment 1 is different with in environment 2.